# How can i solve this error in my code C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, compiler-errors

This error makes my code wrong  & I can't debug my code correctly.

This is my screen when I am debugging my code:

[image]

I can't understand the error. What is it and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you're trying to use the XP-compatible toolset without having it installed? (Project Properties > General >  Platform Toolset). What version of VS is that?

Comment: This isn't a good question for this site. You could [edit] it and improve it greatly by: adding the actual error into your question (not as an image), and adding a [mcve]. Add any other information that may be relevant (IDE, compiler), and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

It means you do not have SDK (and tools) for Windows XP target compilation.

You either need to:

- change platform target of the Project ( Yer Project -> Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset)
- or install that feature (Control Panels -> Programs and functions -> Visual Studio X -> modify -> select "Windows XP support for C++")